# How to make Start up script for Making Application run on startup

Tags: 12.04, scripts, startup, startup-applications

I have one jar which i need to run on startup and no matter whatever user is logged in and that need to take that user name automatcally
here this code can take user name

```
echo $(logname)
```

and this command i need to run on start up.

```
java -jar /home/(username)/VISDashboard2014/VISDashboard.jar
```

so now how can i take dynamically username in to this command.?

Comment: You can use `$HOME` or `$USER` Environment Variables. In which `$USER` provide `<username>` and `$HOME` provide `/home/$USER` path. (You should **replace** `(username)` with `$(logname)` or `$USER`)

Comment: can u post simple command then??

Comment: Yes Dude its working u can post it as ans i will accept it :)

Comment: $USER i am using put it will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following conmand:

In which `$USER` is [environment variable](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) which gives username

```
java -jar /home/$USER/VISDashboard2014/VISDashboard.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

```
java -jar /home/$USER/VISDashboard2014/VISDashboard.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

```
java -jar /home/$(logname)/VISDashboard2014/VISDashboard.jar
```

should work.

Comment: it should work??

Comment: its not working :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a desktop entry (Google for format) with the line `Exec=java -jar $HOME/VISDashboard2014/VISDashboard.jar`.